# How can I write full search index query which will not consider any stopwords?

Tags: mysql, stop-words

I have written a query which will perform Full Text search using full search Index in mysql Table.

But my problem is that when user searches with "to go" then it will not search anything because of stopwords in mysql.

So my question is, how can I write a Full Search query which will ignore the stopwords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To override the default stopword list, set the ft_stopword_file system variable. ([See Section 5.1.4, “Server System Variables”.)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html) The variable value should be the path name of the file containing the stopword list, ***or the empty string to disable stopword filtering***. The server looks for the file in the data directory unless an absolute path name is given to specify a different directory. After changing the value of this variable or the contents of the stopword file, restart the server and rebuild your FULLTEXT indexes.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Comment: one more question? What is the affect of giving the index size and what is the cardinality???