# How to get related questions using title using MATCH() AGAINST()

Tags: php, mysql

Similar to this question:
[Creating a related or similar posts using PHP & MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593413/creating-a-related-or-similar-posts-using-php-mysql) , I want to get related post.

Now, I have a table named **questiontbl** and this is my query:

```
 SELECT *, MATCH(qu_title) AGAINST('second') AS score
 FROM questiontbl 
 WHERE MATCH(qu_title) AGAINST('second') 
 ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5
```

I just only want to get the related question not including the content or details of the question.

I want to retrieve entries but it **returned empty** although i have the following sample title:

1. "The second thing you should do"
2. "Is second thing important?"

Does anybody know this error?

Comment: Is there Full Text index onto qu_title column?

Comment: is the table MyISAM and not InnoDB?

Comment: What do you expect to get? As far as I know MATCH returns true or false value.. you want 1 or 0?

Comment: yup.. I configured it already to FULL Text

Comment: I am expecting that the two titles number 1 & 2 will be shown or displayed.. And so, there should have two results on my query

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797932/mysql-fulltext-match-against-returning-0-results, and did you check with another word which could possibly is not a 'stopword'?

Comment: @mitkosoft you got it right. "second" is a stopword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`second` is a stopword, so they are ignored when using full-text search. See [Stopwords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html).

Comment: Perfect.. wow.. that's cool..  thanks  @Zamrony   .. I tried another keyword and it worked